# how to write unit test for isNullOrEmpty() function

Tags: kotlin

I have a function for validating the request, it can't be null or empty, I can test if the end point is empty, but I can't pass the value as null to the request in test, I will get "NulllPointerException", how can I test null case?

```
fun validateRequest(request: RegisteRequest) {
              validateEndPoint(request.EendPoint)
    }


private fun validateEndPoint(endPoint: String) {
        if (endPoint.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            logger.error("Request is missing EndPoint")
            throw IllegalArgumentException(ERROR_MESSAGE_MISSING_END_POINT)
        }
    }
```

Comment: change type of endpoint to String?

Comment: @mightyWOZ I'm not that understand your question

Comment: `private fun validateEndPoint(endpoint: String?)`

Comment: got your point, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin's type system is able to differentiate between values that can be null (e.g., `String?`) and values that can't be null (e.g., `String`). You can find more details [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html).

In your case you're defining a function that takes in input a non-null String, so if you're invoking it from Kotlin, the Kotlin compiler will make sure you don't pass a `null` value – it'll fail the build if you try to do so.

If somehow you still manage to pass a `null` value (e.g., via reflection or by invoking the function from Java), you'll get a `NullPointerException` (as documented [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#null-safety)), because the Kotlin compiler will actually insert some instructions under the hood to make sure you don't provide a `null` value.

So if your code is meant to be called from Java or if you really want to test what happens if you pass `null`, you'll have to assert that a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

If, instead, `null` is a valid value and you want to handle it differently, you'll have to change the signature of your method so that it accepts a `null` parameter (note the type of the parameter here is `String?`):

```
private fun validateEndPoint(endPoint: String?) {
    ...
}
```